# HAProxy - How to suppress HTTP/1.1 503 from being sent to the client when in maintenance mode

Tags: haproxy, amazon-elb

I'm having problems trying to suppress `HTTP/1.1 503` from being sent upstream from HAProxy. In my environment clients first hit an ELB (classic) instance before traffic is sent on to HAProxy. When we place the backend server/service in maintenance mode by updating the status (MAINT) of the server in the HAProxy backend, HAProxy sends `HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable` with our custom maintenance page to the ELB. However, the client does not see the custom 503 page, rather new connections to the ELB just sit there, waiting.

```
backend frontend-portal
  mode http
  errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/frontend-maintenance.http
  option httpclose
  option forwardfor
  server frontend_service ec2-instance01:80 resolvers nameserver00 check fall 3 rise 2
  server frontend_service ec2-instance01:80 resolvers nameserver00 check fall 3 rise 2
```

I'm looking for a way to suppress or re-write the `HTTP/1.1 503` from being sent so that the ELB serves up our custom maintenance page.